# SVG width 100% not going full width

Tags: css, svg

I have the follow SVG code:

```
       <div className="behaviorPatternsItem" key={item.id}>
          <div className="behaviorPatternsItemStyled">
            <svg height="25" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <g>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width={item.amount} height="25" fill="red"></rect>
                <text x="25" y="17" font-size="12" fill="black"></text>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
```

which is doing the following..

[image]

As you can see, the bottom red bar is not at 100% (like `item.amount` is). The top bar is 10%, middle ones are 90%.

This is what its surrounded by as well as container and row for bootstrap.

```
.scrollableDiv {
  overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.behaviorPatternsItem{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}

.behaviorPatternsItemStyled{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

what am i missing? or any tips?

Comment: Is that all of your code I feel like some css on a parent div/container is setting the width?

Comment: cant be. look at the button line on the div.. thats at 100%. the css code is above on that. the svg is inside that div.

Comment: is it possible that item.amount is being read by your rect as pixels instead of percentage I think i have had something similar to that happen to me before.

Comment: holy hell. thats it! when I change it from 90 to 90% in the json, it works..i just need a function to convert it... THANKS!

Comment: I'll create  an answer would love if you marked this as solved, Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is what your injecting into `item.amount` on the following line: `<rect x="0" y="0" width={item.amount} height="25" fill="red"></rect>`is being read by the complier as a pixel value instead of a percentage.

My solution in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/k1cbjvj7/14/